# Is it possible to re-locate a Kubernetes Pod to a different Node when another Pod's memory usage grows?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

**Context:**

I have a `Pod X` running a Java application that experiences periodic spikes in RAM usage. I aim to ensure that `Pod X` does not encounter an `OutOfMemoryError`. However, allocating the maximum possible RAM by configuring the `QoS` as `Guaranteed` and setting the `-XmX` flag accordingly would result in the inefficient use of computing resources for approximately 95% of the time, given that RAM usage is consistently low during this period.

Conversely, selecting a `QoS` setting of `Burstable` may impact the performance of other Pods(let's say, `Y` and `Z`) running on the same Node.

**Question:**

Is it feasible to relocate `Pod Y` and `Pod Z` dynamically, which don't have extreme spikes in RAM usage, to another running Node, or to schedule `Pod Y` and `Pod Z` on additional Nodes when `Pod X` (`QoS: Burstable`) requires more RAM resources?

Yes, we can of course create a script that monitors the RAM usage. But I am looking for more Kubernetes native approaches.

Comment: Sure, have a script monitor the pod, inject the node name in the other pods manifest and recreate the pod

Comment: @Paolo looking for more Kubernetes native approaches by utilising Kubernetes built-in functionalities, extentions, etc.